# error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' and 'void')|

Tags: c++

outfile not working when calling a function. how can i use the outfile of ofstream to call a function and how to call the reservation using pointer/reference.
returns:
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream}' and 'void')|
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream}' and 'void')|

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Building {
    string buildingcode;
    string location;
    int availablerooms;
};
struct Room{
    double roomarea;
    int roomcode;
    double roomprice;
    Building buildingref;
};
struct Reservation{
    char reservedby[25];
    string reserveddate;
    int stayduration;
    Room reservedrooms[3];
};

void printreservedrooms(Reservation reservation) {
    cout<<" Reserved by: "<<reservation.reservedby<<endl;
    cout<<" Reserved date: "<<reservation.reserveddate<<endl;
    cout<<" Reserver stay duration: "<<reservation.stayduration<<endl;
}


int main()
{
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("Project.txt");
    Reservation reservation[5];
    Reservation *ptr = &reservation[5];

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<" Hello, WellCome to Project Hotel "<<endl;
    cout<<" => building_code: A1528 \n => building_location: CMC "<<endl;
    cout<<"    Room_size         Room_price  available_ rooms  rooms_code  rooms_area     \n"<<endl;
    cout<<" =>  Single bed          200.00          15             101         5.00    "<<endl;
    cout<<" =>  double_bed          350.00          15             202         8.00    "<<endl;
    cout<<" =>  Master_bedroom      500.00          15             303         18.00    "<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<" Enter the information needed below to book a room/s: "<<endl;

            for(int r=0;r<2;r++){
                    cout<<" Maximum reservation allowed for reserver/user "<<r+1<<" is: 3 \n"<<endl;
            //  cout<<"\n Now you have to enter "<<5-i<<" user/reserver information"<<endl;
            cout<<" Enter Full-name: ";
            cin>>reservation[r].reservedby;
            cout<<" Enter a date when to reserve: like 01/08/2013: ";
            cin>>reservation[r].reserveddate;
            cout<<" Enter how long you stays/Duration: ";
            cin>>reservation[r].stayduration;
            cout<<"\n Now you have to enter 3 rooms details you want to have "<<endl;
            cout<<" Use the legend above"<<endl;

            for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
                    cout<<"   Room "<<j+1<<endl;
                    cout<<" Enter the room code of a room you want to have: ";
                    cin>>reservation[r].reservedrooms[j].roomcode;
                    cout<<" Enter the room area of selected room: ";
                    cin>>reservation[r].reservedrooms[j].roomarea;
                    cout<<" Enter the room price of selected room: ";
                    cin>>reservation[r].reservedrooms[j].roomprice;
                    cout<<" \n  Thanks, Now you have "<<j+1<<" room Registered\n"<<endl;
            }
            printreservedrooms(reservation[r]);
            outfile << printreservedrooms(reservation[r]);
```

Comment: what is the meaning of "not working"? Are you actually passing the stream to a function? I dont see it

Comment: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' and 'void')|

Comment: What is the meaning of `outfile << printreservedrooms(reservation[r]);`? `printreservedrooms` returns `void`.. You can't pass such "value" anywhere..

Comment: using ofstream to write the output

Comment: not an issue (because you arent actually doing anything with it): `Reservation *ptr = &reservation[5];` is a pointer to one past the last element of the array. You can get such pointer, but there is little you can do with it. A pointer to the array (more precisely to the first element of the array) is `Reservation* ptr = reservation;` or `Reservation* ptr = &reservation[0];`

Comment: please include the compiler error message in the question

Comment: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' and 'void')|

Comment: @user15317517 "_using ofstream to write the output_" That's not what that line attempts to do. As I already explained: it attempts to write the value **returned** from `printreservedrooms` to `outfile`. Since that "value" is `void` - you can't do that, since `void` caries no value.

Comment: ok so how can i use the outfile??